# I changed the localhost site url on wordpress admin on accident and now I am unable to access the site on localhost

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wordpress-theming

I was working on this site on localhost for a while and changed the site url which was localhost/wordpress to another site it immediately logged me out and said another person is trying to steal localhost's contents. Now I cant access the site on local host and everytime i try to open wp-admin it asks for a login but i can never access it. I can still see the site on localhost/wordpress but all the CSS is gone only the HTML is still there how can I recover the old site back and change the URL.

I tried checking phpmyadmin but my wordpress database is empty for some reason. I had a full site mainly frontend running on localhost it didnt have a backend really. I tried adding on the wp-config file too but it didnt work.